# dnf copr plugin not present in dnf-plugins-core

Tags: plugins, dnf

I want to install a package using `dnf` and `copr`.  Both `copr-cli` and `dnf-plugins-core` are installed.  But `dnf` says `copr` does not exist:

```
$> sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-core
Using metadata from Wed Jan 18 12:48:19 2017
Package dnf-plugins-core-0.1.5-3.el7.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Package dnf-plugins-core-0.1.5-3.el7.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.

$> sudo dnf copr (stuff)
No such command: copr. Please use /usr/bin/dnf --help
It could be a DNF plugin command.
```

Attempting to install `dnf-plugins-copr` by itself also fails:

```
$> sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-copr
Using metadata from Wed Jan 18 12:48:19 2017
No package dnf-plugins-copr available.
Error: no package matched: dnf-plugins-copr
```

Is there another repository I have to enable first?  I am using RHEL 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact on CentOS 7 DNF is too old in repo EPEL7 (version 0.6.x). 
Follow those instructions; they will solve the issue.
[Source: Fresh DNF for RHEL 7 and CentOS 7](http://dnf.baseurl.org/2016/07/01/fresh-dnf-for-rhel-7-and-centos-7)

From this blog:

In order to get DNF-1.1.9 in RHEL 7 or CentOS 7:Enable EPEL repository for additional DNF dependencies:

```
# wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
# sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-7*.rpm
```

Add DNF stack repository:

```
# cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/dnf-centos.repo
[dnf-centos]
name=Copr repo for dnf-centos owned by @rpm-software-management
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-centos/epel-7-\$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-centos/pubkey.gpg
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
EOF
```

Install DNF:

```
# yum install dnf
```

Check if you have the right version:

```
# dnf --version
1.1.9
  Installed: dnf-0:1.1.9_1-16ge900fce.el7.centos.noarch at 2017-02-20 08:57
  Built    :  at 2016-07-01 10:56

  Installed: rpm-0:4.11.3-21.el7.x86_64 at 2017-02-20 08:03
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2016-11-05 23:37
```

Comment: I followed the steps but still my dnf version is 0.6.4.  Do you know why so?

Comment: `-bash: /etc/yum.repos.d/dnf-centos.repo: Permission denied
` error message

Comment: You need to be root or using sudo